# how to handle different accounts with Win8 app c#

Tags: c#, database, windows-8

Hi guy's I just had a wonder moment I want to create an app for c# where users manage information I have read how to create authentication with windows azure ( which seems awesome ) but I was wondering how do apps link a user to their info i.e. when you log into treehouse you only get your Info , how do apps do this after authenticating the user just wondering any guidance would be helpful in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Win8 apps, I believe you should be accessing data through IsolatedStorage which gives a unique store per user per assembly...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage(v=vs.110).aspx